# iOS: method to create two views

Tags: ios

I want to create two side by side views to add to my viewcontroller's view. To keep from repeating code, I am trying to write a generic method to create the two views for me. However, this code isn't working for me. Both view1 and view2 are ivars.

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
  [super viewWillAppear:animated];

  [self makeView:view1];
  [self makeView:view2];
}

- (void)makeView:(UIView*)view {
  CGRect frame = self.view.bounds;
  frame.size.height = frame.size.height/2;
  if (view == view2) {
    frame.origin = CGPointMake(0, frame.size.height);
  }
  view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
  [self.view addSubview:view];
}
```

I think the issue might deal with the line view == view2, some sort of variable reference error. view == view2 always evaluates to true, so view1 never shows up. And in later parts of the code view1 and view2 are nil.

Comment: What, specifically, is going wrong? Does it throw an exception? Crash? Not display your views? Configure the wrong view? Anything in the console?

Comment: == is a pointer reference. try [view isEqual: view2]

Comment: Are `view1` and `view2` loaded from a xib or storyboard?  If so, just set their frames rather than allocating a new view.  If not, what are they (other than empty pointers, one hopes)?

Comment: I'm doing all of it programmatically.

Comment: If they haven't been allocated yet, you're going to be passing a nil pointer for both view1 and view2, then comparing against a nil pointer, which will always be true. the runtime sees if(nil == nil)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's take this step by step to find out the answer.

First, your `viewWillAppear` is being called, and `view1` and `view2` are both `nil` because you have not set them to anything yet.

Then, you are calling your method on `view1`, which is `nil`, so the parameter is going to be the value `nil`.

You create the frame, and then get to your if statement. The parameter (`view`) is `nil`, as we said before, and `view2` is also `nil` because, as we said earlier, it started as `nil` and we haven't set it to anything yet. Because of this, `view==view2` is true because `nil==nil` is true, and you get the frame for the origin that you wanted for view2.

Then, you are setting `view` to a new UIView and adding it to the subView, which does add the view (that you wanted for view2), but you are still not setting the `view1` variable.

After this, you are doing the exact same thing with `view2`, which gives you another view with the exact same frame because `view`, `view1`, and `view2` are all still `nil`.

In order to bypass this, you should actually do the creating of `view1` and `view2` outside of that method (the `view1/2 = [[UIView alloc] init];`) and just do all of the setting parts inside of the method.

Answer (score 0):

If they haven't been allocated yet, you're going to be passing a nil pointer for both view1 and view2, then comparing against a nil pointer, which will always be true. the runtime sees if(nil == nil). Try something like this:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
  [super viewWillAppear:animated];

  view1 = [[UIView alloc] init];
  view2 = [[UIView alloc] init];

  [self makeView:view1];
  [self makeView:view2];
}

- (void)makeView:(UIView*)view {
  CGRect frame = self.view.bounds;
  frame.size.height = frame.size.height/2;
  if (view == view2) {
    frame.origin = CGPointMake(0, frame.size.height);
  }
  [view setFrame:frame];
  [self.view addSubview:view];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a problem of pointers. Try this one:

```
- (void)testExample
{
    object = [NSObject new];
    NSLog(@"Address 1: %p", object);
    [self method:object];
}

- (void) method:(NSObject*) _object {
    NSLog(@"Address 2: %p", _object);
    _object = [NSObject new];
    NSLog(@"Address 3: %p", _object);
    NSLog(@"Address 4: %p", object);
}
```

The output is something like

```
Address 1: 0xcb98ae0
Address 2: 0xcb98ae0
Address 3: 0x11060950
Address 4: 0xcb98ae0
```

So first you get the pointer of the object. Then in the `method:` you get the same pointer. But when you allocate a new object and assign it to the `_object` or your `view` the pointer changes and so your ivars `view1` and `view2` will stay nil.

You have to allocate the views first and than layout them.